# php: day of the week from given date using "date" function: getting one day ahead of expected answer

Tags: php

I have just started with php a couple of days ago. I am trying to get day of the week for a particular date.

```
$firstmonthdate = strtotime("7/1/2015");
//print what my timezone is, for clarity's sake for this question
$myTimezone = date_default_timezone_get(); 
echo $myTimezone."\n"."first day = ".date("r",$firstmonthdate);
```

I get following output for this code:

```
Asia/Singapore
first day = Wed, 01 Jul 2015 00:00:00 +0800
```

So far so good. My problem is in the next line of code:

```
echo "first day = ". strtolower(date("D",$firstmonthdate))."\n";
```

The output for this line of code is :

```
first day = thu
```

As seen above, the correct answer is `wed` but I am getting `thu` and am completely confused. This could possibly be due to timezone difference between singapore and GMT, but I cant figure out why and how to fix it. As seen above, I have set the local time zone correctly and am running this through CLI interface on local laptop. Local webserver is also picking up the same php.ini file.

Any suggestions on whats going wrong here?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Try adding this before your code: `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');` and see if that helps?

Comment: Tried this suggestion, but the output remains same. Thanks for looking up the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you have typo within your variable

```
echo "first day = ". strtolower(date("D",$firsmonthdate))."\n";
                                             ^^
```

instead it should be

```
echo "first day = ". strtolower(date("D",$firstmonthdate))."\n";
                                             ^^
```

If your `error_reporting` is on then you'll get a `Notice: Undefined variable: firsmonthdate`

You need to take care about dates in php. As over here you were getting
date which is `1970-01-01` and if its used in another representation then its `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 +0000`

Comment: sorry, but this typo is in the code I wrote here, not in my file. Apologies for this mistake. I have edited the question here now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I found this typo in one another line on my code. Can't believe I missed this one. There was no error reporting. I'll now look up how to turn on error reporting. Thanks very much for your help here. Sorry for the dumb question :(